# Auth Fail when trying to connect Python to MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to connect to a MongoDB ReplicaSet, but when I try to connect to the database I get the following error in the "for x in mydoc" statement:

> File "C:\Users\Nahuel Gabioud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 159, in _check_command_response raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response) pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.

The code It's the following

```
import pymongo
import urllib

password = urllib.parse.quote_plus("moica2$PerformanceGGR!!")
try: 
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://performance:"+password+"@db-mdb-30.serverurl:27017,db-mdb-31.serverurl:27017,db-mdb-32.serverurl:27017/?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256&replicaSet=rs30&readPreference=primaryPreferred")
    print("Connected successfully!!!") 
except:   
    print("Could not connect to MongoDB") 
mydb = myclient["moica2"]
mycol = mydb["moicaTickets"]

myquery = {"nroTkt": "190701PD0100"}

mydoc = mycol.find(myquery)

for x in mydoc:
  print(x)

input()
```

For security reasons, I didn't post the real url and used "serverurl" instead.

As you can see, I'm using the connection string as in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#standard-connection-string-format

The exception is not caught in the try and except. The error appears in "for x in mydoc".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authentication failed would lead you to believe that the ID / Password is incorrect. If you're behind a corporate firewall, though, it might be a connectivity issue and a poor error message.

I'd suggest downloading / installing Compass and see if that connects with the same connection string / credentials.

https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass

if it does work, I'd suggest this line

```
urllib.parse.quote_plus("moica2$PerformanceGGR!!")
```

is doing something to change the password, and that is where it is failing.

P.s. I'd edit the password out of your question!

Comment: Thanks Allan for your answer. I use NoSQL Manager for MongoDB and it's connecting properly. I tried with to use the password with quote_plus and without it. Although, I can tell you that if I want to import the url in NoSQL Manager I get the following error: "Valid port expected. at line: 1, column: 23."

Comment: Ok, I tried on Compass and you said. First I couldn't connect because the field "Authentication Database" was set to "admin" and it should be "moica2". I edited that and connected properly

Comment: I added "&authSource=moica2" and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Oh man, I just searched half a day why I cannot authenticate! And now I know that it's just because I haven't encoded the "+"... Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention like this way:

```
client = MongoClient('X.X.X.X',port=27017,username='iamlogin', password='abcd',authSource='xyz_db')
```

authSource of your username accessible database name